# Android Twitter Fabric - Library Update

Tags: android, eclipse, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using Twitter's new Fabric SDK with Eclipse. Periodically there is a library update which refreshes or rebuilds the Twitter Fabric Library. When this happens they Twitter project folders located in my project explorer (or package explorer) breaks, breaking whatever app it is added to as well.

I think it has something to do with Android Lollipop, but I am not 100% sure. Every time it breaks, which is like 4 - 5 times an hour, my project build target on my app gets removed and everything breaks and will not compile. When it starts the break, the very first error that I see in the Console is this.

```
    [2015-04-29 12:07:33 - com-digits-sdk-android_digits] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
    [2015-04-29 12:07:33 - com-twitter-sdk-android_tweet-ui] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
    [2015-04-29 12:07:34 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
```

After that happens, the project build target on my app gets removed, and the Twitter sdk starts to refresh itself, and I see some errors like this:

```
[2015-04-29 12:34:53 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] MMyAppPath\kit-libs\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core\res\layout\tw__activity_share_email.xml:45: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginStart' in package 'android'
[2015-04-29 12:34:53 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] 
[2015-04-29 12:34:53 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] MMyAppPath\kit-libs\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core\res\layout\tw__activity_share_email.xml:45: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginEnd' in package 'android'
[2015-04-29 12:34:53 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] 
[2015-04-29 12:34:53 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] MMyAppPath\kit-libs\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core\res\layout\tw__activity_share_email.xml:58: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginStart' in package 'android'
[2015-04-29 12:34:53 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] 
[2015-04-29 12:34:53 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] MMyAppPath\kit-libs\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core\res\layout\tw__activity_share_email.xml:58: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginEnd' in package 'android'
[2015-04-29 12:34:53 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] 
[2015-04-29 12:35:01 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] MMyAppPath\kit-libs\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core\res\layout\tw__activity_share_email.xml:45: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginStart' in package 'android'
[2015-04-29 12:35:01 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] 
[2015-04-29 12:35:01 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] MMyAppPath\kit-libs\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core\res\layout\tw__activity_share_email.xml:45: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginEnd' in package 'android'
[2015-04-29 12:35:01 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] 
[2015-04-29 12:35:01 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core] MMyAppPath\kit-libs\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core\res\layout\tw__activity_share_email.xml:58: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginStart' in package 'android'
[2015-04-29 12:35:01 - com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core]
```

The errors that I see seem to imply that the project build target for Twitter SDK has been incorrectly set. So then I proceed to do the following

- set the com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core folder to project build target 19 Android Open Source Project
- set the com-twitter-sdk-android_twwwt-ui folder to prject build target 19 Android Open Source Project
- set the com-digits-sdk-android_digits folder project build target to 21 Android Open Source Project since it has a values-v21 folder which is using Material Light as a parent in the style.

When I do this, everything compiles fine. After some time ( 15 - 30 minutes ), the library refreshes itself and the errors repeat. I realize that I modified the exact folders that it states the R was modified for, but if I don't do it, it will not build. It's the same thing every 15 minutes. Anyone have this problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: Did anybody know the solution? I also faced that problem and waste my time around 2 hours. Twitter team should solve that problem.

Comment: I found 2 answer in following url.Is it solution? http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/054f8293a400/android-twitter-fabric-library-update.html

Comment: I have left one of those answers and it might work for a while, but the library will eventually refresh and break... it will just take longer. I have recently migrated to Android Studio, and this  problem doesn't exist there at all.

Comment: If so, I have to do the same.I did not use Android Studio coz I am not familiar with all tools from studio .

Comment: Android Studio is a small learning curve, but I would migrate to it asap since this very annoying and time consuming problem isn't on Android Studio at all. Plus, Android Studio is the official IDE for Android Developers so the sooner you migrate, the better.